arch linux not booting and unable to grub-install from within chroot
I have an arch linux setup using lvm which ive updated fine for years until two weeks ago. When I updated two weeks ago, I ran an lvremove of an old snapshot of my root volume and the command hung. I powered off my machine and ever since it wont boot. I have just booted via a live USB to try and figure out what's going on, My fdisk -l output shows /dev/nvme0n1 (this is my only drive) with partitions p1 p2 p3, p1 is my efi partition, p2 is my boot partition, and p3 is my lvm one.
As such I did the following upon booting into the live usb to mount and chroot into my system:
vgchange -ay
mount /dev/vg0/lv_root /mnt
mount /dev/nvme0n1p2 /mnt/boot
mount /dev/nvme0n1p1 /mnt/boot/efi
mount /dev/vg0/lv_home /mnt/home
mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev
mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc
mount --bind /sys /mnt/sys
chroot /mnt /bin/bash

things look "normal" in there (as in, my home all the files, basically as if i had booted normally). Since I don't know why it wont boot, i tried to reinstall grub via grub-install --target=x86_64-efi --bootloader-id=grub_uefi --recheck but this command complains with the error:
"
EFI variables are not supported on this system
EFI variables are not supported on this system
grub-install: error: efibootmgr failed to register the boot entry: No such file or directory
"
(yes the first error message shows up twice). First of all, running grub-install feels like a "guess and check" method (but I don't know what else to try)...and second, when I google around for this error most results suggest I may have booted in legacy mode, but i see the value of 64 if i run cat /sys/firmware/efi/fw_platform_size so i know that's not the case (and when i booted into the live medium it also said UEFI in parens) so I don't understand why i can't seem to grub-install (im not sure that will fix things, but is worth a try as i dont know what else to check)
Edit 1:
Found this thread EFI variables are not supported on this system and got grub-install to run through by passing --no-nvram as a flag, followed that up with grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg (didn't notice much of a diff in the generated grub.cfg from before). Unfortunately still can't boot, when i try to boot from my drive it goes straight back to the bios menu, im not sure how to see "errors" for what's going on..
Edit 2:
Per answer from @grawity below, I added to my mount commands  mount -t efivarfs efivarfs /mnt/sys/firmware/efi/efivars and then i used arch-chroot /mnt instead of chroot /mnt /bin/bash - this time when I ran grub-install --target=x86_64-efi --bootloader-id=grub_uefi --recheck it worked! I followed by grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg and then ran efibootmgr -v and i saw that my first boot order has the grub_uefi HD(1,GPT,some_guid)\EFI\grub_uefi\grubx64.efi pointing to the right place. I then did exit; umount -R /mnt; shutdown now removed the USB and was able to boot back into my system!
It is a mystery how ungracefully powering off my PC while it hung on a stuck "lvremove" could have messed this up...nevertheless happy to have this working again


EFI variables are not supported on this system EFI variables are not supported on this system grub-install: error: efibootmgr failed to register the boot entry: No such file or directory "

You forgot to mount efivarfs at /sys/firmware/efi/efivars.
Use arch-chroot or mount it manually before chrooting.

when i try to boot from my drive

That's most likely the "legacy boot" option (i.e. the one that runs the MBR of that drive). Grub-install doesn't install a legacy MBR when called to install an EFI bootloader.
Or, if the boot option is prefixed with "UEFI:", then it's the one which runs the bootx64.efi file – which grub-install does not install by default. (You'd need to use --removable to get a copy of GRUB at that 'default' location.)
Either way, if you don't have a dedicated boot entry and use the "boot whole disk" option, then you're booting something left over from years ago and not the fresh GRUB installation.

This worked! Thank you so much!! Summarizing this as an edit above.

(weird how something like this would "break" / "disappear from boot options" as a result of non-graceful shutdown during hung "lvremove" command.....)
